# How can I detect an incoming call on Yosemite

Tags: macos, script, facetime

I'd like to detect an incoming Facetime call and run certain scripts as a result. I'd like to achieve something similar to when iTunes pauses when there is an incoming call, but I would run my own scripts.

Any ideas how I can achieve that?